# Add line to configuration file from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, gawk

I am trying to figure out to locate a line in a configuration file, then to drop down two lines then to insert a line of code. I was attempting to do this in awk/sed but got stuck on the carriage return. I not tied to awk/sed but looking for a clean way to accomplish this.

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
```

Then to add a line into that block:

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Is what you're showing the entire configuration file? Can there be more than one `</Location>` in your file? More than one `Order allow,deny`? If yes, how can we know which one is your target?

Comment: You want to do this more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can be used for this. The bellow script will only add text after finding a `<Location />` tag.

```
awk '/\<Location \/\>/{ start=1 } {if(start) ++start; if(start==4) print "  Allow all"} 1' infile
```

For the the bellow input file:

```
stuff
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
more
stuff
```

This script produces:

```
stuff
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
more
stuff
```

If you want to replace several sections like this, the same script can be easily adapted:

```
awk '/\<Location \/\>/{ start=1 } {if(start) ++start; if(start==4){print "  Allow all"; start=0}} 1' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/Order allow,deny/ aAllow all' < yourFile
```

This will output the modified file to **stdout**. 
If you want to modify it in place then ([sed(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)):

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> ```
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

**Explanation:**

```
For each line that matches `/Order allow,deny/`:
     Execute command 'a' (append) with 'Allow all' as parameter
```

http://grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html is an excellent resource to learn more about `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just blindly want to add the `Allow all` statement after any `Order allow,deny` then the following `sed` will work

```
sed -i 's/Order\ allow,deny/Order\ allow,deny\nAllow\ all/' <inputfilename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '/Order allow,deny/a|Allow all' -cx file
```

1. `a` append text and newline
2. `x` save and close